# How do I install this Gnome theme?

Tags: themes

I can't seem to find the answer to this...  I downloaded a theme http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Glassy+Matrix?content=51232. But it doesn't see, to have a file extension, and its a bin file.  When I try to open it, error message says that the file is an unknown file type.  How do I install this theme?

Answer (score 1):

Downloaded file is a `.emerald` file.

To install `.emerald` file you need to install the package `emerald`.

1). Install the package `emerald`. It can be installed with the **ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8** PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install emerald
```

2). Open the Emerald Theme Manager.

You can install the downloaded `.emerald` file with Emerald Theme Manager.

1. Go to `preferences`.
2. select `Manage new Theme`.
3. Select `Import`. Then select the downloaded file.

3). Start your theme.

You can start the emerald theme by the command :

```
emerald --replace
```

Comment: I'm still having issues.  I installed emerald. I ran that command in the terminal & it didnt do anything.I tried looking online and found out that im supposed to used it with compiz mnger.I followed steps here: http://www.noobslab.com/2014/02/emerald-decorator-and-themes-available.html  when I enabled "windows decorations" I get a warning stating that unity can do the same thing, or something along those lines.  When I click to proceed, unity completly went away, I had no options, just a blanks screen.  I had to reinstall ubuntu.  Does compiz window decorations option not work in ubuntu 14.04?